# Inherit another parent CSS property

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` with a certain `color` for text. I want a nested component to use for its `background-color`, the text color of the parent `<div>`.

```
<div style="color: red">
    <div style="background-color: calc(inherit(color))" />
</div>
```

Is this possible in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, use the css value `currentColor`.

```css
.parent {
  color: red;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No way!!! Is `currentColor` the only one? I had no idea about this!! Searching docs on it now, (i cant accept answer until 10min its saying). Thanks for such a fassst reply!

Comment: This is probably the only predefined css variable so far(or as far as I know, if you don't count `inherit`, `initial`, `unset` etc). And it's well supported by all kinds of browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=currentcolor